# Assignment in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I need help with a SQL server query:

I have a table with order IDs and errors assigned to them.

[image]

I need to assign these orders to team members in an equal manner.

[image]

to have a result similar to the following

[image]

[image]

I have been able to use an NTILE partitioned by error, but this would split the orders between team members but not equally.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: use NTILE(countOfTeamMembers)

Comment: Is there any particular way that you are looking to do this?  For instance, it could be done with multiple discrete statements.  What are you looking for?

Comment: Too much sample data...

Comment: @ArtashesKhachatryan I am currently using `NTILE (@NUMBEROFTEAM) OVER (partition by Error order by Error)`, assigning a row number each team member (separate table) then joining the NTILE to the row_number, does that make sense ?

Comment: @STLDeveloper I would like to divide the orders by team member where as much as possible they would get a similar amount of orders and a similar amout of errors

Comment: @jarlh Thank you for your observation, do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: @H.Ben - are you trying to assign each person an equal number of orders, an equal number of errors, or an equal number of types of errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why shouldn't you just distribute errors as they come in.

```
; with octe as
(
select 
   [order #],
   error, 
   row_number() over(order by error asc) r 
from tblorders
),
tcte as 
(
select 
   teammember, 
   row_number() over(order by teammember asc) r
from tblTeam
),
distribution as
(
select 
   teammember, 
   [order #],
   error
from
octe o join tcte t 
on o.r%(select count(1) from tcte)+1=t.r
)

select * from distribution;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `NTILE` function.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[orders](
    [OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ErrorName] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TeamMembers]    Script Date: 10/11/2017 12:53:51 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[teamMembers](
    [Memberid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [MemberName] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (1, N'a')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (2, N'a')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (3, N'a')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (4, N'a')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (5, N'a')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (6, N'b')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (7, N'b')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (8, N'b')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (9, N'b')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (10, N'b')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (11, N'c')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (12, N'c')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (13, N'c')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (14, N'c')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (15, N'c')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (16, N'd')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (17, N'd')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (18, N'd')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (19, N'd')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (20, N'd')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (21, N'e')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (22, N'e')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (23, N'e')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (24, N'e')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (25, N'e')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (26, N'e')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (27, N'f')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (28, N'f')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (29, N'g')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (30, N'g')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (31, N'g')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (32, N'h')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (33, N'i')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (34, N'i')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (35, N'i')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (36, N'i')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[Orders] ([OrderID], [ErrorName]) VALUES (37, N'i')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Orders] OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TeamMembers] ON 
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TeamMembers] ([Memberid], [MemberName]) VALUES (1, N'M1')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TeamMembers] ([Memberid], [MemberName]) VALUES (2, N'M2')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TeamMembers] ([Memberid], [MemberName]) VALUES (3, N'M3')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TeamMembers] ([Memberid], [MemberName]) VALUES (4, N'M4')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TeamMembers] ([Memberid], [MemberName]) VALUES (5, N'M5')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TeamMembers] ([Memberid], [MemberName]) VALUES (6, N'M6')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[TeamMembers] OFF
GO
;WITH cte AS (
SELECT NTILE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TeamMembers))  OVER(ORDER BY orderid) as GroupNum, *
FROM Orders
)

SELECT MemberName, cte.OrderID, cte.ErrorName
FROM cte JOIN dbo.teamMembers ON cte.GroupNum = Memberid
```

Answer (score 0):

This assigns a number to each order starting at 1 and the same to the members. Then using a mod of the order number by the count of members joined to the members number distributes them as equally as possible.

edit: If you order by NEWID() instead of OrderId and MemberId then the asignments will be more random but still even, and who gets the most changes when not even.

```
DECLARE @orders table (OrderId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, Error char(1) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @orders ( OrderId, Error )
VALUES
    ( 1 , 'a' ),
    ( 2 , 'a' ),
    ( 3 , 'b' ),
    ( 4 , 'e' ),
    ( 5 , 'e' ),
    ( 6 , 'a' ),
    ( 7 , 'b' ),
    ( 8 , 'e' ),
    ( 9 , 'd' ),
    ( 10 , 'd' ),
    ( 11 , 'a' ),
    ( 12 , 'e' ),
    ( 13 , 'e' ),
    ( 14 , 'c' ),
    ( 15 , 'i' ),
    ( 16 , 'b' ),
    ( 17 , 'f' ),
    ( 18 , 'g' ),
    ( 19 , 'c' ),
    ( 20 , 'b' ),
    ( 21 , 'f' ),
    ( 22 , 'g' ),
    ( 23 , 'c' ),
    ( 24 , 'i' ),
    ( 25 , 'g' ),
    ( 26 , 'h' ),
    ( 27 , 'i' ),
    ( 28 , 'h' ),
    ( 29 , 'd' ),
    ( 30 , 'c' ),
    ( 31 , 'i' )
;

DECLARE @members table (MemberId int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED, MemberName varchar(50) NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO @members ( MemberId, MemberName )
VALUES
    ( 1, 'John Smith' ),
    ( 2, 'Ted Rogers' ),
    ( 3, 'Amy Williams' ),
    ( 4, 'Natasha James' ),
    ( 5, 'Ahmed Benali' ),
    ( 6, 'Darshit Khatri' )
;

DECLARE @memberCount int = ( 
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM @members 
    );

WITH 
Orders AS
(
    SELECT OrderId, Error, Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OrderId)
    FROM @orders
),
Members AS
(
    SELECT MemberId, MemberName, Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY MemberId) - 1
    FROM @members
)

SELECT M.MemberName, O.Error
FROM Orders O
JOIN Members M ON O.Number % @memberCount = M.Number
;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  o.Order#,
        o.Error,
        s.StaffName
FROM    (
            SELECT  NTILE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Staff)) OVER(ORDER BY Order#) as n,
                    *
            FROM    OrderError
        ) o
        JOIN (
                SELECT  StaffName,
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY StaffName) as MemberID
                FROM    Staff
             ) s
            ON o.n = s.MemberID
```